# Improving code - create new column using R which counts distinct entries in one column of a data set filtered by another column

Tags: r, distinct, mutate

I have some working code (below) which, for the second column it creates it: creates a new data frame, filtering the original data frame by a specific column; counts distinct entries of another column for this filtered data frame; left joins this result to the original data frame.

I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to achieve the same result (i.e. instead of having to create a new data frame and left joining to the original data frame).

```
# calculate initial column
data <- data %>% 
  group_by(column_a) %>% 
  mutate("total_sub_rows" = sum(column_b == 'specific')) %>% 
  ungroup()

# is there a way to get below into above code?
new_column <- data %>% 
  filter(column_b == 'specific') %>% 
  group_by(column_a) %>% 
  summarise(sub_rows = n_distinct(column_c)) %>% 
  ungroup()

data <- data %>% 
  left_join(new_column)
```

Please see above, the code works, I am just interested if there is a better way to write this.

An example of the end result is this:

[image]

Comment: could you please give a view of what your data look like? it would help a lot with helping you out.

Comment: hello! I added an image of what it would look like, just in excel, hope that is helpful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, an example with iris dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
iris[, c(1,2,5)] %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(total_sub_rows = sum(Sepal.Length < 5),
         new_column = n_distinct(if_else(Sepal.Length < 5, Sepal.Width, NA))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

In your specific case, it could be:

```
library(dplr)

data %>% 
  group_by(column_a) %>% 
  mutate(total_sub_rows = sum(column_b == 'specific'),
         new_column = n_distinct(if_else(column_b == 'specific', column_c, NA))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Species total_sub_rows new_column
          <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>            <int>      <int>
 1          5.1         3.5 setosa              20          8
 2          4.9         3   setosa              20          8
 3          4.7         3.2 setosa              20          8
 4          4.6         3.1 setosa              20          8
 5          5           3.6 setosa              20          8
 6          5.4         3.9 setosa              20          8
 7          4.6         3.4 setosa              20          8
 8          5           3.4 setosa              20          8
 9          4.4         2.9 setosa              20          8
10          4.9         3.1 setosa              20          8
# … with 140 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see m
```